# phpunit mock method called in constructor

Tags: constructor, mocking, phpunit

I test a config class, which is parsing a config file and allows me to get the various settings for an app.

My goal is to mock the `parse()` method of the Config class, which is called in the constructor and to set what this method is returning in the constructor.

This way, it prevents `file_get_contents()` from being called (in the `parse()` method) and enables me to have a Config class with the `config` property already set to contain an array of properties.

But I haven't succeeded doing that.

Here is the code:

The config class:

```
<?php namespace Example;

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

class Config
{

private $parser;
private $config;

public function __construct(Parser $parser, $filePath)
{
    $this->parser = $parser;
    $this->config = $this->parse($filePath);
}

public function parse($filePath)
{
    $fileAsString = file_get_contents($filePath);

    if (false === $fileAsString) {
        throw new \Exception('Cannot get config file.');
    }

    return $this->parser->parse($fileAsString);
}

public function get($path = null)
{
    if ($path) {
        $config = $this->config;

        $path = explode('/', $path);

        foreach ($path as $bit) {
            if (isset($config[$bit])) {
                $config = $config[$bit];
            }
        }

        return $config;

    }

    return false;
    }

}
```

The test:

```
<?php namespace Example;

class ConfigTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    private function getConfigTestMock($configAsArray)
    {
        $parser = $this->getMockBuilder('\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser')
            ->getMock();

        $configMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Example\Config')
            ->setConstructorArgs([$parser, $configAsArray])
            ->setMethods(['parse', 'get'])
            ->getMock();

        $configMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('parse')
            ->willReturn($configAsArray);

        return $configMock;
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function get_returns_false_if_no_path_given()
    {
        $configMock = $this->getConfigTestMock(['param1' => 'value1']);

        // Testing further...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to make a functional test mocking the interaction with the file system, without do partial mocking of the tested class.

I recently discover the [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) library used in a [great article](http://williamdurand.fr/2013/11/13/ddd-with-symfony2-basic-persistence-and-testing/) of William Durand about Symfony2 and DDD.

So you can install this library in your composer.json (I tested the solution with the 1.4 version) and try this example test class:

```
<?php


namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Tests;


use Acme\DemoBundle\Example\Config;
use org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStream;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

class ConfigTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{


    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function valid_content()
    {
        $content = "param1: value1";

        $root      = vfsStream::setup();

        $file = vfsStream::newFile('example.txt')
            ->withContent($content)
            ->at($root);

        $filepath = $file->url();
        $parser = new Parser();

        $config = new Config($parser, $filepath);
        $this->assertEquals("value1", $config->get("param1"));

    }

}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for this great solution and the links! Wish I could give you more points for this answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

For test the `Config` class you need to mock only the `Parser` and use the real Config class. As Example:

```
<?php


namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Tests;


use Acme\DemoBundle\Example\Config;

class ConfigTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    private function getConfigTestMock($configAsArray)
    {
        $parser = $this->getMockBuilder('\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser')
            ->getMock();


        $parser->expects($this->once())
            ->method('parse')
            ->willReturn($configAsArray);

        $configMock = new Config($parser,"fakePath");

        return $configMock;
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function get_returns_false_if_no_path_given()
    {
        $configMock = $this->getConfigTestMock(['param1' => 'value1']);
        $this->assertEquals("value1",$configMock->get("param1"));

        // Testing further...

    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I realized I made a mistake in my question which made it look like the problem was with the `parse()` method of the YAML Parser while actually my question is about how to mock the `parse()` method of the Config class and control what it returns in the constructor.

Comment: Hi @IamZesh i see your update, i will investigate and response to you